# What are these wheels called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I've been looking for the name of the wheel of which a few are visible on this picture (not the object itself, but the wheels that are used on it!):

[image: Gadget that looks like the mechanical display mechanism of an odometer]

I've been looking for terms like "counter wheel", "counter reel", and so on - but can't seem to find anything that names the actual wheels themselves.

I know that these wheels have a name as I've seen it before, but I can't recall what it was. If I had to describe it, "a numbered wheel that represents a counted digit, either stand-alone or as part of a larger number".

Comment: But that's just it - *wheels* is the word

Comment: Combinations, counters, digit keys, number wheels - it can depend on the context.

Answer (score 5):

If they were oriented to face you axle-on, they would be called [dials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dial_%28measurement%29), of course.  As they're not, the best I can think of is ***digit wheel***.  I can't find an official definition page, but [Alibaba has a category page](http://www.alibaba.com/showroom/digit-wheel.html) for that term, and everything on it looks like what you're talking about...

Comment: According to alibaba: it's a [counter digit wheel](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/305334248/counter_digit_wheels.html).  Nice link!

Comment: That sounds like something I'd attempt to use if you attacked me with a digit wheel. ;-)

Comment: Yes, Counter digital wheels; here's some [Google images](http://www.google.com/search?q=counter+digit+wheels&start=10&hl=en&client=safari&sa=N&tbo=u&tbm=isch&source=univ&ei=mNe6T-nDNIjp6gGK2oDYBw&ved=0CIABELAEOAo&biw=1024&bih=644); also includes some distance measuring tools

Answer (score 3):

I've always called them *[rotors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotor_machine)*.  (The caption of the first picture at that link starts off with "A series of three rotors...")  However, the aforementioned *barrel, drum, wheel* terms are more common than *rotor* in discussions of [mechanical counters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter#Mechanical_counters), where the term *counter wheel* often is used.  Two other terms used are *disc* and *ring*; a wikipedia *[row counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_counter_%28hand_knitting%29)* article refers to *knurled number rings* in its "Pendant knitting counters" section and to *number discs* (or *disks*) in other sections.  However, the *disc* terms are specific to flat counters with rotating discs, instead of to cylindrical parts as contained in those Veeder-Root-style mechanical counters.

Answer (score 2):

Due to their cylindrical shape the wheels in a mechanical counter like this might be referred to as **barrels** or **drums**.

Comment: To be pedantic, they don't have to be cylinders, they could be decagons.

Answer (score 1):

You can also find **odometer wheel**

Comment: An odometer is an instrument that measure distances. The device represented in the picture is just a mechanical counter that can be used as an indicator for an odometer, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would call them ***dials*** despite the orientation - to me, a *dial* is a disc with numbers on that is rotated, and is an appropriate word to use for any such disc used in a safe, combination lock or analogue number counter such as the one pictured.

However, it does seem from a quick Google that the [distinction that MT_Head is making](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/67620/62605) is potentially a technically accurate<sup>1</sup> one. So, if you reject *dials* on grounds of pedantry, I would suggest using something like *rotating discs* or *number discs*. (*Discs* is what the [Wikipedia page on combination locks uses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination_lock) under several pictures of these types of number dials). These sound more natural - to me -  than the phrases with *wheels* in.

<sub><sup>1</sup> I've judged this by usage only.</sub>